# material-ui table: how to make style changes to table elements

Tags: html, css, material-ui

I'm using 'material-ui' and trying to get a table element to change color when the element has a certain value.  Below is the code I tried, if the cell value is "Out of Zone", the background should go red'ish.  The table renders fine, but toggling the color change doesn't work, how come (or is my approach all wrong)?

```
function renderRowColumn(row, column) {
    if (row.status == "Out of Zone") {
        return (
            <TableRowColumn className="ae-zone">
                {row[column.name]}
            </TableRowColumn>
        )
    }
    return (
        <TableRowColumn>
            {row[column.name]}
        </TableRowColumn>
    )
}
```

In style.css:

```
.ae-zone {
    background-color: '#e57373';
    font: "white";
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your specificity on the css selector is not high enough. The rendered TD element has an inline style in which the background property is getting inherited which is overriding your class style.

Is there any reason since you already have the logic seperated out you don't just use inline styles for something like this.

```
<TableRowColumn style={{backgroundColor:'red', color: 'white',}}>{row[column.name]}</TableRowColumn>
```

This is definitely working well and I tested it.

Your other option would be to add !important to your css.

```
td.ae-zone {
  background-color: '#e57373' !important;
  color: "white" !important;
}
```

I think if I had to chose though I would recommend the first as it is cleaner.

Comment: The inline styling partly works, it just colors the background of the entire row red (not just the cell) and does not change the font color.  The class approach does not work at all for me.

Comment: @atommike First off, my apologies had a typo. Need to be using color css property not font.
For the row coloring issue could you maybe elaborate on how you are iterating the table cells in the table row? Maybe putting your whole render function above will help give a better idea of what might be happening. As I am able to use inline styling and apply to a single cell.

Comment: Note that this does not work anymore, as `TableRowColumn` was removed in the 1.x branch

Answer (score 4):

Don't put quotes around color values in css:

```
.ae-zone {
    background-color: #e57373;
    color: white;
}
```

Also, it's `color: white`, not `font: white`.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do this :

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

// Declare this bellow your import
const UseStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        "& .MuiTableBody-root": {
            backgroundColor: "#121212",
        },
    },
});

// Declare this after your declaration page 

const classes = UseStyles();

// Now in your Table, use the class : 
<Table className={classes.root}>
    <TableHead>
        {...}
    </TableHead>
</Table>
```

With the inspector you can see each automatic class from Material UI and target them in the makeStyle.

Be carefull to use the same code example :

```
"& .MuiClassNameYouWantTarget" : {
    textAlign: "center",
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time the Table takes the default style, so if the styles didn't get applied try appending `!important` to the style. This worked for me.

```css
.ae-zone {
    background-color: '#e57373' !important;
    color:red;
}
```