# How to reference in directory of SCSS file from component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, webpack

Currently I have the following directory structure:

```
stylesheets
..modules
...._all.scss
...._colors.scss
..partials
...._all.scss
...._Home.scss
..main.scss
```

And in my `_Home.scss` I have:

```
@import '../modules/all';

.headerStyle {
  color: pink;
  font-size: 15;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

And in my `main.scss` I import all the `_all.scss` in stylesheets folder like:

```
@import 'modules/all'
@import 'partials/all'

html { font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; }
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: orange
}
```

And lastly in my component, I would import the stylesheet like so:

```
import '../../stylesheets/main.scss'

...

<div className="headerStyle">Header</div>
```

Yet, the div is not being styled with `.headerStyle` in `_Home.scss`. I checked the directory path to `main.scss` and it is correct, and I'm not getting any errors.

And the following is actually being applied:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: orange
}
```

What could I be doing wrong? And is there a better way to import stylesheets into a component rather than having to define it every time for a component?

Thank you in advance and will upvote/accept answer.

Comment: Are you importing `_Home.scss` into `partials/_all.scss`? `@import 'Home'`

Comment: first of all, is it a typo in `@import 'modules/all'`? shouldn't it be `_all`? secondly, what is the content of `_all.scss` files?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following successfully (using plain HTML and the [Scout-App](http://scout-app.io/) to transform SCSS to CSS):

Edit: As mentioned I've never used React but based on this post [hugogiraudel.com](http://hugogiraudel.com/2015/06/18/styling-react-components-in-sass/) it should be the same syntax as in my solution (more or less/on first sight ;-) ).

Edit 2: I started using SCSS just a few days ago myself. As far as I can tell your only errors are the few typo's shown in my example. Since 'body' is applied I assume the import statement in your component is correct for React.

If there is a better solution to do imports into components has to be answered by someone else. But it looks like the author of the linked blog post has another approach and there is also a github repository available.

directory structure:

```
- project_folder
    - index.html
    - stylesheets
        - main.scss
        - partials
            - _all.scss
            - _Home.scss
```

Index.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- NOTE: 'css_stylesheets' is the folder where the 
                   Scout-App added the transformed CSS files -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_stylesheets/main.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- NOTE: I don't know anything about React but 
                   in HTML the attribute is 'class' not 'className'
                   Edit 3: 'className' is correct, my bad -->
        <div class="headerStyle">Header</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

stylesheets/main.scss

```
@import 'partials/all'; // Your missing here a semicolon (;) I think

html { font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; }
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: orange; // here too but wasn't crucial
}
```

stylesheets/partials/_all.scss

```
@import '_Home.scss';
```

stylesheets/partials/_Home.scss

```
.headerStyle {
  color: pink;
  font-size: 30px; // I added here pixels because Firefox ignored it otherwise
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Comment: Actually was trying it on `<TableHeaderColumn>` of http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table like `<TableHeaderColumn className="headerStyle">`, but doesn't work.

Comment: Is there anyway you can provide the rendered html of React? Does it work if you use the 'style' attribute to set the style of <TableHeaderColumn>?

Comment: Based on the material-ui docs and this post [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053163/material-ui-table-how-to-make-style-changes-to-table-elements) the inline styles could be your problem. But it's just guessing for me now. If this isn't the problem someone more experienced has to take over here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have configured Webpack to use `stylesheets` directory so you could use

```
import 'main.scss'
```

instead of

```
import '../../stylesheets/main.scss'
```

Answer (score 1):

@fingerpich hit on a good solution for making your paths simpler. You can set up an alias to your stylesheets directory, and then always import relative to that directory:

Webpack config:

```
{
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // the path needs to resolve relative to the files where you're importing them
      stylesheets: path.resolve(__dirname, '../stylesheets')
    }
  }
}
```

Docs: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias

Component file:

```
import 'stylesheets/main.scss'
```

Also you can let webpack resolve imports from inside your sass files by adding ~ to the front of the path. Then you can write your imports there just like in your component files and they'll resolve to your alias:

```
@import '~stylesheets/modules/_colors.scss'
```

Docs: https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader#imports

Answer (score 1):

In the overall code which you have provided only one thing is missing semi-colon(;)
While using SCSS we have to use semi-colon to terminate the statement.

Here is the updated code :

```
@import 'modules/all';
@import 'partials/all';

html { font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; }
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}
```